# What does cd * do in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I saw someone use `cd *` and then use other commands like ls et al after that.

What does it do? Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell expands `*` to an alphabetical list of the current directory's contents.

`cd` ignores all arguments after the first.

In lucky and/or extremely controlled circumstances, you can rely on the first item in the wildcard expansion to be the directory you want to `cd` into.

This may be marginally useful and/or entertaining if you have just created and descended into the current directory and populated it with a single subdirectory. I find it hard to imagine it could have other actual uses.

Comment: If you want to learn one new shell trick today, learn the Bash default binding for recalling the final argument of the previous command for editing, `M-.`, instead.

Answer (score 3):

This command:

```
cd *
```

will **only work if first list from current path is a directory** since it expands to very first entry (file or directory) in the current path. You can see what comes first by doing `echo *`.

I would suggest not really relying on it since alphabetically first expansion can give you a file also like `.bashrc` or some other file name starting with dot.

Comment: doesn't it autocomplete, so it only just selects the first match? (which happens to work only if the first match is a directory)

Comment: Yes it does and I have added in my answer not to use it since it may fail.

Comment: `*` is not supposed to match any file name starting with a `.`.

Comment: That actually depends on `dotglob`. I have it on in my shell so it matches dot files also.